# stock span problem error getting wrong ans when stack is empty

Tags: python

its a general stock span problem:
iam doing this problem for last 3 hrs but couldn't find the bug in my code
for input ['74', '665', '742']
ans should be "1 2 3"
but i am getting ans "1 1 3"

```
n=len(a)
print(calculateSpan(a,n))
output is 1 1 3

if get this types of error where should i go ,any website were some one can help me

def calculateSpan(a,n):
    list=[]
    tmpst=[]
    tmpst.append(0)
    list.append(1)
    for i in range(1,n):
        if a[tmpst[-1]]>a[i]:
            list.append(1)
            tmpst.append(i)
        else:
            while (len(tmpst)>0) and a[tmpst[-1]]<a[i]:
                tmpst.pop()
            #list.append(i-(tmpst[-1] if len(tmpst)>0 else -1))
            list.append(i+1 if len(tmpst)<=0 else (i-tmpst[-1]))
            tmpst.append(i)
    return list
```

Comment: Can you explain more ? Why that output for that input ? What's the principle

Comment: The stock span problem is a financial problem where we have a series of n daily price quotes for a stock and we need to calculate the span of stock’s price for all n days. 
The span Si of the stock’s price on a given day i is defined as the maximum number of consecutive days just before the given day, for which the price of the stock on the current day is less than or equal to its price on the given day.
For example, if an array of 7 days prices is given as {100, 80, 60, 70, 60, 75, 85}, then the span values for corresponding 7 days are {1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 6}.

Comment: there is a solution given on exactly that site where the description is from (go to the python tab, this also gives the correct result for your example): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-stock-span-problem/

Comment: yes i  know that but i want to debug my code i want to know what went wrong